# Sails.js can't enable CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, sails.js

I have configured my Sails.config.cors and set the allRoutes to true. However, I cannot do POST request which is giving me this cors error:

> https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Here's how I access it:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
      url: 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        file: file,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '******'
      }
    }).then(function (resp) {
      console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
      console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
      var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
      console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
  };
```

cors.js:

```
 allRoutes: true,
  origin: '*',
   methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
```

Comment: Please post here your `config/cors.js` file

Comment: It only contains allRoutes = true, i haven't uncommented the others.

Comment: Try comment out `origin` to be `*` and `methods`, and make sure `methods` includes `POST`.

Comment: It doesn't work too. I added my cors.js above

Comment: is Access-Control-Allow-Origin set on the server which is getting request?

Comment: Any luck ?  I am facing the same issue

Comment: Is proxy is enabled in your system